# Creating XML structure via tags with ExtendScript Toolkit

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt, adobe-indesign, extendscript

I'm using InDesign CS6 and I'm trying to build my first Javascript within InDesign. I want to be able to create an entire XML structure whenever someone tags a frame. Ideally, it would work something like this: When text frame.tagged(record/item/@name="copy"), create Structure. I'm reading through a few books and trying to wr4ap my head around how InDesign scripting works, but I haven't been able to translate the examples into this thing I need to do. I appreciate any help. Thank you - Nathan

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep playing with ExtendScript and it will work eventually.

For what you are trying to achieve you need to create tag first and reference your text frame and associate it with this tag. Try this:

```
var myTag = app.activeDocument.xmlTags.add("myXMLTag");
var myFrame = app.activeDocument.textFrames[0];
app.activeDocument.xmlElements[0].xmlElements.add(myTag, myFrame);
```